# Getting JsonElement into CosmosDB in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

You'd think this would be easy as falling off a log, but I'm stumped.  I have an ASP.NET 3.1 core web api (using System.Text.Json):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(JsonElement dzc)
```

Which in turn calls a service:

```
public async Task AddItemAsync(JsonElement dzc)
{
    var id = dzc.GetProperty("id").GetString();  // these are both valid
    var userid = dzc.GetProperty("userid").GetString();

    await this._container.CreateItemAsync<JsonElement>(dzc, new PartitionKey(userid));
}
```

This results in: Message: {"Errors":["The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing"]}

Or if I get the raw text:

```
public async Task AddItemAsync(JsonElement dzc)
{
    var id = dzc.GetProperty("id").GetString();  // these are all valid
    var userid = dzc.GetProperty("userid").GetString();
    var raw = dzc.GetRawText();

    await this._container.CreateItemAsync<string>(raw, new PartitionKey(userid));
}
```

and raw is:

```
{
    "id": "foozy",
    "userid": "foozy",
    "name": "Jayb",
    "fc": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "capacity": "10",
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -71.073283,
                        42.417500
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This results in: Message: {"Errors":["One of the specified inputs is invalid"]}

All I'm really trying to do is shovel some Json directly from an API into CosmosDB without using C# classes.  What is the magic incantation?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer...you can't via `CreateItemAsync`.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.cosmos.cosmoscontainer.createitemasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#parameters) explicitly states that an id prop is required, which by definition does not exist on on either `JsonElement` or `string`.

A better option would be to use `CreateItemStreamAsync` which allows you to pass in the raw stream directly and appears to bypass an Id property requirement, per the [example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.cosmos.cosmoscontainer.createitemasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#parameters).

```
using (Response response = await this.Container.CreateItemStreamAsync(partitionKey: new PartitionKey("streamPartitionKey"), streamPayload: stream))
{
    using (Stream responseStream = await response.ContentStream)
    {
        //Read or do other operations with the stream
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string responseContentAsString = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David L, your suggestion worked great!  Here's what I ended up with:

```
public async Task AddItemAsync(JsonElement dzc)
{
    var id = dzc.GetProperty("id").GetString();
    var userid = dzc.GetProperty("userid").GetString();

    var raw = dzc.GetRawText();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(raw);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        await this._container.CreateItemStreamAsync(stream, new PartitionKey(userid));
    }
}
```

I'm curious if the copy can be avoided.